# php mysql json document makeup

Tags: php, mysql, json

I'm using this but of code to generate json data form a mysql table :

```
$sql = "select * from u3D15";
$result = mysql_query($sql);
$json = array();
if(mysql_num_rows($result)){
    while($row=mysql_fetch_row($result)){
        $json['title'][]=$row;
    }
}
mysql_close($db_name);
echo json_encode($json);
```

But this is what the json looks like: `{"title":[["1","kevin","t0E0GAA"]]}`

I like it to be:

```
{
   "title" : "Decode JSON",
   "ID" : 20,
   "buttons" :
   [
     {
       "title" : "kevin ",
       "image" : "t0E0GAA"
     },
     {
       "title" : "lora ",
       "image" : "v1AWYqR"
     }
   ]
}
```

How can i change the makeup of the file?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Setup the array yourself to get formatted results.

```
$json = array(); //create empty array
$json["title"] = "Decode JSON";
$json["ID"] = 20;
$json["buttons"] = array(); //empty nested array - we will fill it by MySQL results

$sql = "select * from u3D15";
$result = mysql_query($sql);
if(mysql_num_rows($result)){
    while($row=mysql_fetch_row($result)){
        $json["buttons"][]=$row; //insert mysql rows to buttons array
    }
}
mysql_close($db_name);
echo json_encode($json);
```

Comment: this prints `{"title":"Decode JSON","ID":20,"buttons":[["kevin","t0E0GAA"],["tim","uGmSNxk"]]}` without the `"title":"kevin","image":"t0E0GAA"`

Comment: got it changed `mysql_fetch_row` to `mysql_fetch_assoc`

Answer (score 1):

It is very simple, just construct your array like this :

```
$json['title']='Decode JSON';
$json['ID']='20';
$json['buttons']['title']='kevin';
$json['buttons']['image']='t0E0GAA';

echo "<pre>";
echo json_encode($json);
```

Answer (score 1):

Try below code:

```
$sql = "select * from u3D15";
$result = mysql_query($sql);
$json = array();
if(mysql_num_rows($result)){
    while($row=mysql_fetch_row($result)){
        $json['title']=$row[1];
        $json['ID']=$row[0];
        $json['buttons']['title']=$row[1];
        $json['buttons']['image']=$row[2];
    }
}
mysql_close($db_name);
echo json_encode($json);
```

Hope this solves your purpose..

Comment: this works but it only prints 1 of the 2 rows, how can i fix this?

Comment: Because you are using mysql_fetch_row instead of mysql_fetch_assoc ..I thought you require only single row :)